# Select observations in R based on maximum number listed in a column

Tags: r, dplyr

I hope I've done this correctly! I have two data frames:

```
teachers = structure(list(Teacher = c(123L, 123L, 123L, 123L, 124L), 
    tStudents = c(3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L), Term = c(1801L, 1802L, 1801L, 1803L, 1802L), 
    Course = structure(c(5L, 6L, 7L, 6L, 8L), .Label = c("ENGG", 
    "ENGG2", "LITT", "LITT2", "MATH", "MATH2", "PHYS", "SCIE"
    ), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Teacher", "tStudents", "Term", "Course"), row.names = c(NA, 5L), class = "data.frame")
enrols = structure(list(UniqueStudent = structure(c(3L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 4L), 
    .Label = c("1801-ENGG-N1-abcd1@abc.edu.au", "1801-MATH-C1-abcd1@abc.edu.au","1801-PHYS-L1-abcd1@abc.edu.au", "1802-MATH2-G1-abcd1@abc.edu.au", "1802-SCIE-K2-abcd1@abc.edu.au"), class = "factor"), Term = c(1801L,1801L, 1801L, 1802L, 1802L), Student.Email.Addresses = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "abcd1@abc.edu.au", class = "factor"), ID = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "s12344", class = "factor"), 
Gender.Description = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "M", class = "factor"), 
Age = c(12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L), Program.Short.Description = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "LSC1", class = "factor"), Term.CC.CN = structure(c(3L, 
2L, 1L, 5L, 4L), .Label = c("1801-ENGG-N1", "1801-MATH-C1", 
"1801-PHYS-L1", "1802-MATH2-G1", "1802-SCIE-K2"), class = "factor"), 
Course.Code = structure(c(4L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 3L), .Label = c("ENGG", 
"MATH", "MATH2", "PHYS", "SCIE"), class = "factor"), Class.Number = structure(c(4L, 
1L, 5L, 3L, 2L), .Label = c("C1", "G1", "K2", "L1", "N1"), class = "factor"), 
Teacher = c(123L, 123L, 125L, 124L, 123L)), .Names = c("UniqueStudent", "Term", "Student.Email.Addresses", "ID", "Gender.Description", "Age", "Program.Short.Description", "Term.CC.CN", "Course.Code", "Class.Number", "Teacher"), row.names = c(NA, 5L), class = "data.frame")
```

`teachers$tStudents` lists the maximum number of students allowed to be allocated to a teacher per Term and Course. I've also pre-merged the Course enrolments in the "enrols" data to list the Teachers for each course.

So, what I need to do is create class lists from the `enrols` data using the `teachers` data by `c("teacher", "Term", "Course")` but my class lists can only select a maximum value of students based on the number listed in teachers$tStudents. Ideally, I'd also like to select a representative distribution of students so that the new class lists have both genders, different ages and are from different Program.Short.Description.

I've tried merging in different ways in dplyr and can create full lists with all students but haven't been able to use the teachers$tStudents column to limit the number of observations to select. Is this possible?

Comment: Can you show us the selecting observations code you have tried so far? Merging in the `tStudents` into `enrols` is easy enough in `dplyr` using `enrols %>% left_join(teachers, by = c("Term" = "Term", "Course.Code" = "Course", "Teacher" = "Teacher"))` but it sounds like you want something more than that.

Comment: To firstly make it easier to link the lists, I created unique identifiers in both lists using `teachers$T.T.CC <- with(teachers, paste0(Teacher, "-", Term, "-", Course))
enrols$T.T.CC <- with(enrols, paste0(Teacher, "-", Term, "-", Course.Code))`. I then used `dplyr` to merge the lists: `classList <- enrols %>%
  left_join(teachers, by = "T.T.CC") %>%
  group_by(T.T.CC) %>%
  slice(1:3)`. This limited the selection to only 3 rows so I haven't been able to limit the selection to the numbers listed in `tStudents` yet.

Comment: I'm also trying `SamplingStrata` at [link](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/SamplingStrata/vignettes/SamplingStrataVignette.pdf) but haven't got through it yet because it's quite complicated.

Comment: I think I've worked out a quick and easy way of doing this which seems to have selected a nice distribution of students. I've used `filter` in `dplyr`. The 3 lines of code (!!) were `classlist_test <- classLists %>% 
  group_by(T.T.CC) %>% 
  filter(n() == tStudents)`. Hope someone else finds this useful!

Comment: Correction: `filter(n() <= tStudents)`